# Wildfly hangs up after any Exception.

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, ejb

I have a with Wildfly 8.2.0 and the Technologies: EJB JPA JSF Prmefaces.

My Problem is, that the wildfly Server hangs up if any exception occurs. For example a NullpointerException.

The Problem is that if User 1 get a NullpointerException of a method, then  User 2 can't Login if he calls the Website. Because the Wildfly hangs up and the loading Symbol is showing for ever.

Do you have any idea in what direction i have to look for solution ?

Comment: How do you start the server? Is it by any chance in debug mode run by an IDE? Do you have any custom (global)exception handling code in your app?  Could you try to reduce the deployed application to a simple servlet that always triggers the exception and reproduce it there?

Comment: Need some more details: stacktraces, some code, launch configuration. Without that we can only say "something is wrong".